# Number of Binary String

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $x=x_1x_2\dotsm x_n$ be a binary string. A $k$-substring of $x$ is a period of continuous bits, i.e. $x_ix_{i+1}\dotsm x_{i+k-1}$. I want to count the number of all the binary strings whose any two arbitrary over-lapping $k$-substrings is never Reverse-Complement 【Reverse-Complement means reverse one of substring and add to the other (the bit-sum modulo 2), a $k$-length string with all bits equal to 1 is obtained】.

Is there a theory about counting the number of such binary strings?

Comment: Is the sum modulo $2$? i.e., you want an *odd* number of $1$'s in the $k-$substrings?

Comment: The sum happens in bits, and modulo 2. I edit my question again, that makes me clear.

Comment: It might be clearer to define the reverse complement $\overline{w}$ of $w$ recursively as $\overline{0} = 1$, $\overline{1} = 0$, $\overline{uv} = \overline{v} \, \overline{u}$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor So the condition is that $w_1\ne\bar w_2$ for any overlapping $k$-substrings $w_1$, $w_2$, right?

Comment: That's what I understand, yes.

Comment: Is $k$ given and fixed?

Comment: If $k$ is fixed as $3$ or if it is fixed as $4$, it amounts to count binary strings that avoid $0011$, $0101$, $1010$ and $1100$ as substrings.

Comment: If $k$ is fixed as $2\ell-1$ or if $k$ is fixed as $2\ell$ with $\ell\in \{2,3,\dots\}$, it amounts to count binary strings that avoid $u\overline{u}$ as a substring for any binary string $u$ of length $\ell$, where $\overline{u}$ is the reverse complement of $u$ defined in @PeterTaylor 's comment.

Comment: Then the problem amounts to constructing the De Bruijn graph for given $k$, removing edges corresponding to the forbidden substrings, and then counting walks in this graph via the transfer-matrix method.

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier Something's wrong, no? Any string of length $k=2\ell-1$ automatically avoids substrings of the form $u\bar u$ for $u$ of length $\ell$ since $u\bar u$ has length $k+1$. Yet not all strings of length $2\ell-1$ are allowed.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე All strings of length $n=k=2\ell -1$ *are* allowed, because a string of odd length $k=2\ell -1$ is never equal to its reverse-complement (being of odd length, its has got a central bit, which cannot be equal to its own complement).

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier Oh sorry I thought you mean fixed $k$ and arbitrary $n$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I do. For $k=2\ell-1$ fixed, for any $n$, avoiding any $u\overline{u}$ of length $2\ell$ is necessary because the $k$ first bits of $u\overline{u}$ overlap with its $k$ last bits on $k-1$ bits and they reverse-complement each other, which we want to avoid. It is sufficient as well, because once you avoid any such $u\overline{u}$ of length $2\ell$, you automatically avoid any longer self-reverse-complement substring $w\overline{w}$.

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier Yes, clear, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, thanks for all you guys ^_^

Answer (score 2):

The even length substrings which equal their own reverse complement are precisely the even length palindromes when you reverse every other letter in $x$. Therefore you are looking for the number of strings of length $n$ that do not contain any palindromes of length $2\ell := 2\lceil k / 2 \rceil$. Let's call this number $f_\ell(n)$.

Counting the number of words of length $n$ avoiding length $k$ palindromes sounds like a very natural problem in combinatorics on words, but I couldn't find anything after a quick google search, so I'm not sure there exists a nice exact formula. However you can find some rough bounds on its behavior for variable $\ell$ and $n$ using counting and probabilistic arguments.

For example, there is an upper bound of $f_\ell(n) \leq (2^{2\ell} - 2^\ell)^{\lceil n / 2\ell\rceil} \approx e^{-(2^{-\ell-1}/\ell) \cdot n}\cdot 2^n$, because there are $2^{2\ell} - 2^\ell$ possibilities for each segment of length $2\ell$.

For a lower bound, note that cyclic strings of length $2^{\ell-1}$ are expected to have half a palindrome. Thus there are at least
$$\frac{2^{2^{\ell-1}}}{2\cdot2^{4\ell}}$$
different strings of length $2^{\ell-1}$ same length $2\ell$ prefix and suffix, which we can concatenate arbitrarily without introducing palindromes. This gives a lower bound of
$$f_\ell(n) \geq \left(\frac{2^{2^{\ell-1}}}{2\cdot2^{4\ell}}\right)^{\lfloor n / 2^{\ell-1}\rfloor } \approx 2^{-(4\ell+1)2^{-\ell+1}\cdot n}\cdot 2^n.$$
Therefore $f_\ell(n) = 2^{n(1-2^{-\ell + o(\ell)})+O(2^\ell)}$.

Comment: $f_2(n)=2a(n+2)$ for $n\ge 3$ where $a(n)$ is OEIS's A000930 Narayana's cows sequence.